# arrow function inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

i have this object literal

```
let p = {
    name : 'Amir',
    say: () => {
        console.log(this.name)
        console.log(this)
    }
}
```

and I want the say function works using this

```
p.say();
```

but the arrow function obviously gets the window object as `'this'`. I know I could use a regular function for `'say'` instead of arrow and it will work fine.

BUT
I would like to ONLY change the call to say function to make it work, but the binding won't work.
I mean something like `p.say.bind(p)()`  or `p.say.call(p)` aint gonna work as desired.
Is  it possible to change the call to function ONLY and not the say function?

Comment: As the [documentation of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) explains, they don't have their own `this` and, because of that, they cannot be bound to an object neither using `bind()` nor `call()` or `apply()`.

Comment: The answer is "no". It's not possible by ONLY changing the call site. The reason is that an arrow function simply does not have a `this` binding at all. The `this` you're using is accessed from its outer scope, like any other identifier that your function closes over. It would be like if you defined a `foo` variable outside the function, and then put `console.log(foo)` inside. Because the function doesn't have its own `foo`, it gets the outer one.

Comment: `p.say = p.say.bind(p)` ...